# I want to delete unmatching records from two columns of tables?

Tags: sql

I want to delete unmatching records from two columns of tables by comparing them?

Comment: Welcome to SO, check this link to see how to ask sql questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2348125

Comment: You can't "delete records" from "a column" - you can set a column's value to `null`  or delete a complete row.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
DELETE FROM @tbl WHERE Column1 != Column2

    OR

DELETE A FROM @tbl1 A
LEFT JOIN @tbl2 B
ON A.Id = B.Id 
WHERE B.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: This is for SQL related dbms.

Comment: SQL is a language specified by ANSI/ISO. Many products have their own versions/extensions to the steandard. Your DELETE is not ANSI SQL compliant, so it would be nice if you informed OP which dbms it is written for.

Answer (score 0):

if you want compare two tables :

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE (COLUMN)
NOT IN
(SELECT Table2.COLUMN  FROM Table2,TABLE1 where Table2.COLUMN=TABLE1.COLUMN)
```

else:

```
    DELETE FROM Table1 where column1!=column2
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Left Join to delete unmatching records.

```
DELETE t1 FROM @TABLE1 t1 
LEFT JOIN @TABLE2 t2 on t1.NAME1 = t2.NAME2
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=30a43f154c014bc90e9d3b3f84d78655)

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: The SQL query will work for any DB. The demo provided is for SQL Server.